# ChromeDriver issues implementing in java with maven

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I cant seem to get a headless chromedriver setup in java working.

I am running Java8 on Ubuntu 18.04 with netbeans 8.2

Is it possible I am getting the error below because I don't have maven installed correctly?

I have made the chromedriver executable and added the path using:

```
  String chromeDriverPath = "/home/bob/NetBeansProjects/ScrapeLetGo/src/main/resources/chromedriver.exe";
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromeDriverPath);
```

I have added dependencies and more dependencies to POM.XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>ScrapeLetGo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>



                                 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.openqa.selenium.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>scrapeletgo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/webdriver-common-0.9.7376.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>   

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.openqa.selenium.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>scrapeletgo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>/home/bob/NetBeansProjects/ScrapeLetGo/src/main/resources/selenium-chrome-driver-2.26.0.jar</systemPath>


</dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.14.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

However, when I go to instantiate with:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
                options.addArguments("--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=1920,1200","--ignore-certificate-errors", "--silent");
                WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
                driver.get("https://us.letgo.com/en?searchTerm=dell%20optiplex");
```

I get errors and/or it doesn't compile.

Here are some errors I get:

```
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1
```

and also this

```
ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.HasInputDevices
```

Comment: You did not pass ChromeOptions in ChromeDriver constructor.

Comment: Ok I updated it to include options being passed in. I still get the same errors however

Comment: Why do you have multiple versions of `selenium-java`? Keeping your `pom.xml` clean of redundant dependencies comes first. You may want to read on Transient Dependencies in Maven so you understand what it does before attempting to use it. You also need to point to the chromedriver binary (`.exe`) not just to the folder where it's at.

Comment: Ok thank you for the info. I will try to clean the POM.XML file. On your second point: You are saying I need to specify "/path/to/chrome.exe" formatted like that?

Comment: Yes, an absolute path to the chromedriver.exe.

Comment: I deleted a lot of stuff from my POM.XML and made the setPath an absolute path

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179278/discussion-between-daveyman123-and-silver).

Comment: It would seem that cleaning up my POM.XML helped

Comment: Good. What you just experienced is called "dependency hell". You should only keep the things you need in the pom.xml. Maven also automatically downloads dependencies of dependencies. For example, if you put in `selenium-server`, no need to put `selenium-java` because server depends on java. Maven will automatically download. This is called transient dependencies. The Maven Repo site shows what transient dependencies a dependency has.